# What does JSX stand for?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What does JSX stand for?

I am referring to the JSX that is defined as a XML-like syntax extension to ECMAScript, which has become quite popular with the increasing popularity of ReactJS.

Comment: JavaScript Extensible Markup Language

Answer (score 74, accepted):

JSX stands for ***J**ava**S**cript **X**ML*. With React, it's an extension for XML-like code for elements and components. Per the React docs and as you mentioned:

> JSX is a XML-like syntax extension to ECMAScript without any defined semantics

From the quote above, you can see that JSX doesn't have defined semantics, it's just an extension to JavaScript that allows to write XML-like code for simplicity and elegance, and then you transpile the JSX into pure JavaScript function calls with [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement). Per the React tutorial:

> JSX is a preprocessor step that adds XML syntax to JavaScript. You can definitely use React without JSX but JSX makes React a lot more elegant.
>
> Just like XML, JSX tags have a tag name, attributes, and children. If an attribute value is enclosed in quotes, the value is a string. Otherwise, wrap the value in braces and the value is the enclosed JavaScript expression.

Any code in JSX is transformed into plain JavaScript/ECMAScript. Consider a component called `Login`. Now we render it like so with JSX:

```
<Login foo={...} bar={...} />
```

As you can see, JSX just allows you to have XML-like syntax for tags, representing components and elements in React. It's transpiled into pure JavaScript:

```
React.createElement(Login, { foo: ..., bar: ... });
```

You can read more [at the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. This is definitely the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: It was created by Facebook! It is optional. You can use React with pure JS too.. But JSX makes life easier

Comment: Man, it's annoying how docs don't usually start with the actual meaning of the acronyms.

Answer (score 4):

JSXJavaScript stand for syntax extension.It's similar to XML. You can use a simple JSX syntactic transform with React.

Answer (score 3):

According to [React Doc](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)  :

```js
const element = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
```

*This funny tag syntax is neither a string nor HTML.*

*It is called JSX, and it is a syntax extension to JavaScript*

What JSX does is  producing  React “elements” . **but how ?**

Under the hood, JSX is being compiled by JavaScript compiler  named **Babel** and converted to vanilla javascript

this is a class component in React  using JSX :

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Bonjour {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="momo" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

this is the same class component without JSX :

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, `Bonjour ${this.props.name}`);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Hello, {name: 'momo'}, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

As you see every **JSX** is just a calling for  **React.createElement()**
So whatever you can do with JSX you can do it just with plain JavaScript . but for more simplicity of your code it is much better to use JSX

Comment: Why did you answer on a question that has already an accepted answer?

Comment: the  accepted answer  is totally correct . I just tried to make another simple, uncomplicated and straightforward explanation  with example

Answer (score 2):

**JSX** stands for **JavaScript XML** (e**X**tensible **M**arkup **L**anguage).

**JSX** is one of the examples of **syntactic sugar** in JavaScript.

Syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express.

Component written using **JSX**:

```
const MyComponent = () => { 
  return <div> 
    <p>This is not HTML...!</p> 
    <p>Wait...Is this JavaScript?</p> 
    <p>No, What the hell is this?</p> 
    <p>This is JSX.</p> 
  </div> 
}
```

In case we don’t want to use **JXS** then the corresponding code for the above code snippet will look like.

```
const MyComponent = () => { 
  return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement("p", null, "This is not HTML...!"), React.createElement("p", null, "Wait...Is this JavaScript?"), React.createElement("p", null, "No, What the hell is this?"), React.createElement("p", null, "This is JSX.")); 
};
```

Read More:

[Syntactic sugar - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

[Introducing JSX – React](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 1):

**JSX** means a way of writing code which will be ultimately transpiling to javascript which is understood by the browsers ,it keeps the code readable

Example:-

1)*HeadingComponent without using JSX*

```
import React, { createElement } from 'react';
const HeadingComponent = () => {
  return createElement('div', { id: 'title' }, [
    createElement('h1', { id: 'heading1' }, 'Hello World 1'),
    createElement('h1', { id: 'heading2' }, 'Hello World 2'),
    createElement('h1', { id: 'heading3' }, 'Hello World 3')
  ]);
};
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<HeadingComponent />);
```

2)*HeadingComponent using JSX*

```
import React from 'react';
const HeadingComponent = () => {
  return (
   <div id="title">
    <h1 id="heading1">Hello World 1</h1>
    <h1 id="heading2">Hello World 2</h1>
    <h1 id="heading3">Hello World 3 </h1>
   </div>
 );
};
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<HeadingComponent />);
```

***As defined in the second example by using JSX this way the component is by default calling React.createElement to create the DOM as defined in the first example without using JSX***

Answer (score 0):

JSX - JavaScript Syntax Extension
A preprocessor step that adds XML syntax to JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

JSX stand for Javascript with XML like syntax

```
 eg.
<div>
</div>
or <td>
</td>
```

same like XML format put it in return form in class defined

Comment: Why are you answering a question which has already has an accepted answer (which has a much higher level of detail)?