# How does javascript deal with jsx

Tags: javascript, jsx, interpreter, precompile

So i came across jsx lately, and i wondered how jsx actually works under the hood, does the javascript code get precompiled to convert the jsx to regular javascript (if so how would this work?) or can the javascript engine directly compile jsx?

```
<some>jsx here</some>
<some>jsx here</some>
var = "regular javascript";
```

**edit** I know what jsx does and what it is meant for, what i am asking is how does jsx get converted to javascript code. Or do browsers do this?

if this question is offtopic, let me know so i can remove it, or move to the right site.

Comment: yes, it's precompiled. Usually through [babel](https://babeljs.io/) involving a build pipeline with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). why don't you download some react example and check the `scripts` section in the `package.json`

Comment: @Thomas ah ok, how does babel do this? does it just to some type of regex to convert the code, to js?

Comment: No, that's way more complex. It's parsing your entire project (including the JSX) into an AST, does stuff to the AST and converts the result to JS and writes it to a js file

Comment: ok thanks, thats all i needed to know!

Answer (score 0):

It's duplicate: [What does JSX stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461805/what-does-jsx-stand-for).
But in short it's pre-compiled into plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

actually jsx does not do any thing with your code .

when you start the react app project you should use the `babel` and `babel` have lot's of `plugins` and `presets` and they are convert your code to the regular javascript code 
for the browsers 
and check this out
[babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/)

after that you could check this out
[webpackjs](https://webpack.js.org/)