# Why do I get this error in the return function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is my code:

```
    export default function Mio() {
      const app = document.getElementById("app");
      const Avatar = (params) => {
        const src = `https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/${params.id}.jpg`;
        return `
        <div>
          </br>
          <picture>
            <img src="${src}" />
            ${params.name}
          </picture>
        </div>
        `;
      };
      return (
        <div class="box01" style="background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)">
        <div class="box02" style="background:rgba(50, 255, 0, 0.70)">
          <center><h1>Desarrolladoras</h1></center>
          <center><h2>Android</h2></center>
          <center>
            Avatar({ id: 1, name: "Andrea" })
            Avatar({ id: 2, name: "Miluska" })
          </center>
        </div>
        <div class="box03" style="background:rgba(50, 0, 255, 0.70)">
          <center><h1>Desarrolladoras</h1></center>
          <center><h2>iOS</h2></center>
          <center>
            Avatar({ id: 3, name: "Raida" })
            Avatar({ id: 4, name: "Tania" })
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
```

That shows errors. But when I run this code, replacing return function with this:

```
    app.innerHTML = `
        <div class="box01" style="background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)">
        <div class="box02" style="background:rgba(50, 255, 0, 0.70)">
          <center><h1>Desarrolladoras</h1></center>
          <center><h2>Android</h2></center>
          <center>` +
            Avatar({ id: 1, name: "Andrea" }) +
            Avatar({ id: 2, name: "Miluska" }) +
          `</center>
        </div>
        <div class="box03" style="background:rgba(50, 0, 255, 0.70)">
          <center><h1>Desarrolladoras</h1></center>
          <center><h2>iOS</h2></center>
          <center>` +
            Avatar({ id: 3, name: "Raida" }) +
            Avatar({ id: 4, name: "Tania" }) +
            `</center>
        </div>
      </div>
      `;
```

I don't get an error, but I want it to be able to work with the return function.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is? Are you wondering why the code changes when compiled by react? --- _"That shows errors"_ - what errors?

Comment: `Avatar({ id: 1, name: "Andrea" })` in JSX needs to be `<Avatar id={1} name="Andrea" })/>`

Comment: Also share the error you are getting

Comment: It looks like you're [confusing JSX with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39461805/1218980). JSX is not a simple string literal that's inserted in the DOM, it gets transformed to actual JavaScript. Unless you're not using React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSX component is not formatted the right way.

You can't just add a function into JSX, you have to use the JSX syntax for your `Avatar` components provided you want to render that HTML.

So `Avatar({ id: 1, name: "Andrea" })` becomes `<Avatar id={1} name="Andrea" />` etc

In addition to that I made changes to your `Avatar` component so it returns actual JSX instead of a string like you had and fixed up some other errors you had on the component like `class` -> `className` and passing an object to `style`.

So your code would look like this:

```js
export default function Mio() {
  // const app = document.getElementById('app'); // unused-var
  const Avatar = (params) => {
    const src = `https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/${params.id}.jpg`;
    return (
        <div>
          <br/>
          <picture>
            <img src={src} />
            ${params.name}
          </picture>
        </div>
     );
  };

  return (
    <div className="box01" style={{ background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)' }}>
      <div className="box02" style={{ background: 'rgba(50, 255, 0, 0.70)' }}>
        <center>
          <h1>Desarrolladoras</h1>
        </center>
        <center>
          <h2>Android</h2>
        </center>
        <center>
          <Avatar id={1} name="Andrea" />
          <Avatar id={2} name="Miluska" />
        </center>
      </div>
      <div className="box03" style={{ background: 'rgba(50, 0, 255, 0.70)' }}>
        <center>
          <h1>Desarrolladoras</h1>
        </center>
        <center>
          <h2>iOS</h2>
        </center>
        <center>
          <Avatar id={3} name="Raida" />
          <Avatar id={4} name="Tania" />
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```